# How to display images with CarrierWave in Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, carrierwave, datamapper

I have struggled a lot with CarrierWave, so I made a small program to see if I could make that work:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'carrierwave/datamapper'

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
end

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/photogallery.sqlite3")

class Image
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :title, Text

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_migrate!

get "/" do
    @images = Image.all
    erb :index
end

post "/" do
    image = Image.new(:title => params[:title])
    image.image = params[:image]
    image.save

    redirect "/"    
end

__END__

@@ index
<% @images.each do |image| %>
    <p>
        <%= image.title %>
    </p>
    <a href="<%= image.image.url %>">
        <img src="<%= image.image.url %>">
    </a>
<% end %>

<form action="/" method="post">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>

    <label for="image">Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="image"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

It seems that I am unable to display the image when I upload an image from my computer. It is as if the images are not saved anywhere, so they can't be retrieved.

The anchor tag correctly references where the images should be, but there are no images.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't put solutions in your question. SO isn't a message board, it's more like an online Q/A reference or a cookbook. As such, questions and answers are separate and have to be kept separate. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271399/128421 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434/128421.

Comment: Thanks, i know. But apparently my answer was too long to post as a comment, so i had to make an edit. But will keep in mind, thanks

Comment: And I only just now discovered that you can press "answer your question", so I'm just a bit thick I guess

Comment: "Thanks, i know. But apparently my answer was too long to post as a comment, so i had to make an edit."? Um, no. The site has reasons for enforcing certain things. SO wants you to do the tour, and when you do they award you points that give you new privileges. It's a carrot on a stick. Please go through the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59049764/128421) for @MrMos...

Nevermind, I found out. I did this instead:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'carrierwave/datamapper'

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    storage :file

    def store_dir
        'images'
    end
end

class Image
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :title, Text

    mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_migrate!

get '/' do
    @images = Image.all
    erb :index
end

post '/' do
    Image.create(params[:image])
    redirect to('/')
end

__END__

@@ index
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></div>
            <input type="text" name="image[title]" />
            <input type="file" name="image[file]" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
        <% @images.each do |image| %>
            <p><%= image.title %></p>
            <img src="/images/<%= images.file_identifier %>" />
        <% end %>
    </body>
</html>
```